# Javascript and HTML bad DOM trees

Tags: javascript, html

This is more of a conceptual question than a coding problem. HTML5 is very robust in the sense that it will still render your page if you're missing tags or attributes (ie. missing body tags) but will it still parse a DOM tree? If so, our DOM tree is "incorrect" but our page still renders. What're the consequences of having a bad DOM tree?

Comment: No, there can only be a consistent DOM tree. A browser will make assumptions to build a valid DOM tree. These assumptions may not be what the author intended, but at least the DOM tree will be valid.

Comment: The HTML5 specs defined how a html parser should behave if required tags are missing or if the html code is not well-formed in another way, so that the resulting DOM is valid and consistent between different parsers.

Comment: HTML5 is a standard. It doesn't do any rendering. Rendering is a function of the browser engine after it's parser that implements the standard handles the document. The tolerance of a given browser to a bad document varies as it basically attempts to fill in missing pieces with a series of educated guesses. Likewise, the consequences of having non-compliant HTML code vary based on how well the browser engine's guesses line up with the original intent.

Comment: Also, you should read this to better understand how a browser actually works under the covers: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/.

Comment: @JamieSee For html5 [8.2 Parsing HTML documents](https://www.w3.org/html/wg/spec/parsing.html) defines how the browser has to correct not well formed html documents. It was defined for html5 to ensure that all engines correct non well formed code the same way.

Comment: @t.niese Yes, but that is a draft standard and there are still variations in how browsers actually implement even ratified standards. Because of that, although there is a basic set of non-compliant cases that are handled well and consistently by pretty much all browsers, some cases still produce different results in each browser.

Comment: @JamieSee I corrected the link to the non draft one. `[...]still variations in how browsers actually implement even ratified standards[...]` but those variations should be considered as bugs. The point is, that html5 defines this error handling so that browsers wont have to do _educated guesses_.

Comment: @t.niese Browsers are STILL doing educated guesses. The HTML5 standard just attempts to codify the most common set to improve consistency. It's not hard to demonstrate that there are still variations in handling and probably always will be. The point is that Garbage In - Garbage Out still applies. Browsers do their best to handle all the weirdness, but the best thing is to feed them good HTML5 compliant code in the first place whenever possible.

Comment: Specifically what type of problems would you run into with "bad" html code? If the DOM tree is correct and consistent, there shouldn't be any repercussions with bad code right?

Comment: Never mind, after reading the provided papers there are no real errors and like you guys said the web browser will do it's best to correct syntax errors. You might get something you don't expect which is the consequence of parsing bad html code